# Exist $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in a open and bounded $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and, for all $a \in \overline{U}-U$ we have
$$f(x) \to 0, \ x \to a ;$$
Then exist a $x_0 \in U$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: So...what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as we approach the boundary, we can extend $f$ to a continuous function on $\bar{U}$ by defining $f$ to be $0$ on $\bar{U}-U$.  Since $U$ is bounded, so is $\bar{U}$, so $\bar{U}$ is actually compact.  A continuous function must achieve its max and min on a compact set.  If $f$ is constant, we're done.  Otherwise, since $f$ is constant on $\bar{U}-U$ it must have either a min or max on the interior, i.e. in $U$.  Use what you know about derivatives at a max or min.